# Finding a nested value in a document using the PHP driver

Tags: php, mongodb, nested

Okay so here is my issue. Each user in my db has field called 'friends'. Each time a friend is added, it gets a unique id and is also keyed in the friends field according to a string typed version of this id, like so:

```
$user          =   AppDatabase::getInstance()->getUser($user_id);
$user_friends  =   $user['friends'];
$new_friend    =   array
                                    (
                                        'friend_id'=>new MongoId($friend_id),
                                        'nickname'=>(string)$nickname,
                                        'friendpic'=>''
                                    );

$user_friends[(string)$friend_id] = $new_friend;
```

This is all good and works fine, I get a result in the db that looks like this:

```
'friends':
{
503da7ba65d351681a00000c
{
'friend_id':{$oid:503da7ba65d351681a00000c},
'nickname':"Heisenberg",
'friendpic':''
}
}
```

Now, what I need to be able to do is find a friend by only using their friend_id and not knowing the user_id (or anything about the user). I'm a little confused on how to do this, basically the process in my head is:

- Pass in the friend's id
- Query the user's collection
- Find all "user_friends" fields
- From this, find the key which matches the id I passed in originally
- End up with the correct friend object

None of what I am trying really works though. Perhaps I have structured the data incorrectly. If someone could put me on the right path I'd really appreciate it.

Cheers!

Comment: I am confused, Does the friend_id relate to a user_id or something and you are trying to find where that user is friends with someone?

Comment: Let's use a different example. Instead of a friend, let's say it was a piece of furniture. So each user has a set of furniture pieces. I need to be able to find or edit a specific user's furniture piece without necessarily knowing the user's id. Does it make more sense?

Comment: Ok so they are independant of the root collection they are not nested sets of users. Hmm ok I think I might have an answer

Answer (score 0):

Basically I think what you wanna do is create an edit form for, say, a friend that will span multiple users. So lets break this down:

- You have the friend ID
- All friends within all users have the same data (or maybe not and friend id is unique either way this should work)
- You need to update that friend id without knowing the id of the root document

One thing that can help you here is v2.2 of Mongo which can actually pick this out using the positional operator from the main document giving you a similar result to:

```
'friends':
{
503da7ba65d351681a00000c: {
    'friend_id':{$oid:503da7ba65d351681a00000c},
    'nickname':"Heisenberg",
    'friendpic':'' }
}
```

Irrespective of how many friends you have in that list. I personally have not yet used this querying method however here is the JIRA for it: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-828 so you can play around however a query like:

```
find({'friends.503da7ba65d351681a00000c': {$exists: true}}, {'friends.$':1})
```

Might do the trick, I hear sometimes you need to use `$elematch`. I am unsure if this would totally work since I am not sure if friend_id is duplicated but still worth a try.

Pre 2.2 this is a little harder and as you say you must get out all friends where that friend id exists:

```
find({'friends.503da7ba65d351681a00000c': {$exists: true}});
```

And then go through that to pick them out (pseudo code):

```
foreach(result as id => friend){
    if(id == id_i_am_looking_for) return friend;
}
```

And then you can use that doc and update it. To place it back in the DB (providing you have the full object at hand) you can do:

```
db.update({'friends.503da7ba65d351681a00000c': {$exists: true}}, 
    {$set: {'friends.$' : new_friend_object}});
```

If you don't have the entire friends object to play with then you will need to update per field either way it is relatively the same.

After that you should now be able to update a friend without knowing the user_id.

Hope it helps,

Comment: I've since changed my schema to pull the friends out into another collection and to associate them via inserting the user's id in each document, I also keep an array inside of the user's doc for all the friend's ids. I found this easier than normalizing the data. I think probably what you've suggested will work, I don't have 2.2 yet as I'm using MongoHQ for hosting currently and they haven't updated. This looks like it will work though. Thanks a lot!